# How to solve this error in Flopy for head table boundary?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boundary, flopy

I've been trying to put my head data in my model using MODFLOW6 but I get the following error:

```
MFDataException: An error occurred in data element "strt" model "model" package "ic". The error occurred while setting data in the "__init__" method.
Additional Information:
(1) Unable to set data "strt" layer 0.  Data is not in a valid format.
(2) Error occurred while adding dataset "strt" to block "griddata"
```

I already tried anything possible, the strt is an array from a raster (boundary of head table data), the raster is in .tiff format as well as the other layers of the model. Also, I've made sure that they have same pixel size and extent. How can I solve this error? 
Thank you

Comment: Can you show how you create your raster?

Comment: I just loaded the raster data with GDAL and I am using it as an array. What I was trying to do was adding my constant head boundary (strt). I had the polygon and the raster, I extracted by mask only those pixels within the polygon on ArcMap and implemented them in my code, when I tried running it (having assigned the number 1 to existing cells) I got that error :(

Comment: It would be helpful for others to see your code, including any library import statements, you are using to load your raster and feed it into Flopy. Your problem seems to be that whatever the array data you are feeding in to the `strt` variable is not in a valid format.